# Choosing rails version in RadRails 2.0.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana, radrails

I've created rails application using rails 3.0.3
After adding it to RadRails it still recognize my project as rails 2 application and searching for "scripts/server"
How and where can I change settings of default rails version?

Answer (score 0):

RadRails 2.x isn't up to date and doesn't handle Rails 3. Please try Studio 3: http://aptana.com/products/studio3/download

It contains embedded Ruby/Rails support.